# Why is conversion from basic_ostream to string stream allowed under clang?

Tags: c++, gcc, stream, clang, stdstring

Why can the following code be compiled with clang under Mac OS X:

```
std::string{ (std::stringstream{} << std::this_thread::get_id() ).str() };
```

GCC is more correct in such afford: std::basic_ostream has no member str(). And indeed in libc++ header operator<< for std::thread::id return std::basic_ostream, so why can previous code be correct in clang?

Comment: libstdc++ has an extension that returns a reference to the derived type if the stream is an rvalue.

Comment: Maybe you mean that libc++ has extension not libstdc++? Because in my case compilation fail with libstdc++, and succeed with libc++. Has you are reference for this extension description?

Comment: Right, it's libc++ not libstdc++. The extension is not standard but it can be found here https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/system/include/libcxx/ostream#L1059